# What are ARC implications for using 'init' in non-initializer method names for singleton only classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

So it has been my understanding that using init within a method name is not advisable if that method doesn't actualize initialize a new instance of the object. However, what is the case for a singleton type class? If I do something like this:

```
+ (MyClass*) sharedInstance {

    __block MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

And then have another method:

```
- (void) initializeInstance {
  // Do some stuff
  // Never call the init method
}
```

Will there be extra retain cycles or other odd ARC behavior if I do this?

Comment: I think that good programming practice would be, as you say, to not to start the method name with `init`, as convention would suggest that this would return a pointer to the new instance. Why not `configureInstance` or something like that, rather than `initializeInstance`? It just eliminates any ambiguity.

Comment: In first place, you **should not** misuse naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `-initializeInstance` is not a problem. This does not get classified into the `init` family, so the compiler does not treat it specially. According to [the documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family), in order to be classified into the `init` family, it must meet the following rules:

1. The first component of the selector must be either `init`, or must begin with `init` followed by any character other than a lowercase letter. `initializeInstance` does not meet this rule.
2. Furthermore, the `init` method must return an Obj-C object. `initializeInstance` does not meet this rule either. I believe if this rule is violated that causes a compile-time error rather than simply not treating the method as `init`.

Comment: Good to know, but still worth avoiding that kind of code, because the next developer hasn't read this answer and is needlessly worried.